# Unable to import convos and utterances from QnAMaker using Botium CLI

Tags: chatbot, azure-qna-maker

Our bot is using QnA Maker. Using Botium CLI command like:

**botium-cli qnamakerimport --buildconvos=true**

I got the error -
**FAILED: 400 - {"error":{"code":"KbNotFound","message":"Knowledge base not found.","details":[{"code":"KbNotFound","message":"cc10c31a91114039886bb49da0c446d9"}]}}**

The botium.json file looks like:

```
 "botium": {
        "Capabilities": {      
          "PROJECTNAME": "ActivebotTest",
          "CONTAINERMODE": "qnamaker",
          "QNAMAKER_KNOWLEDGEBASE_ID": "xxxxxxx",
          "QNAMAKER_RESOURCE_NAME": "yyyyyy",
          "QNAMAKER_ENDPOINT_KEY": "zzzzzz",
          "QNAMAKER_RESOURCE_KEY": "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv",
          ....
       }
}
```

Could you please let me know if this command is supported?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, this command is supported. What did you use as your knowledgebase id ?

Comment: Hi Florian, Thank you for the reply. I used the knowledge base Id as per doc. ______________________________POST /knowledgebases/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/generateAnswer Host: yyyyyyyyyyy.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker Authorization: EndpointKey zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz Content-Type: application/json {"question":"<Your question>"} _____________________________________________________________________________________ (replaced with our real KB id, resource name, endpoint key taken from QnA Maker Settings). Is something missed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: looks ok. where did you get the resource key from

Comment: Hi Florian,
Thank you for your reply.
I got the resource key for our chatbot from MS Azure>>QnA Maker>>Cognitive Services>>Keys and Endpoints->Key 1
Thank you in advance.

Comment: For the resource key,in the Azure Portal, find these keys on the Cognitive Services resource on the Keys and Endpoint page - they are different from the endpoint keys in the qnamaker

Comment: Yes, I used the Key that I found in Azure Portal on Cognitive Services >>Keys and Endpoints. I used Key1 copied from the page. Still not working with this resource key.
Thank you for reply.